# Got "Call to undefined function SoapServer()" when trying to create wdsl with php under xampp

Tags: soap, wsdl

xampp 1.7.7, soap module enabled,php 5.3.8.Apache/2.2.21,
Anybody can shed a light on this?TIA

Answer (score 0):

did you new soapserver first ?

test by this, no error for soapserver class

```
  ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");
  $server = new SoapServer("example.wsdl");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php

and check php_soap.dll in php/ext/ directory and config php.ini

```
;extension=php_soap.dll ->  extension=php_soap.dll
```

restart apache